Trying to pass array of dictionaries from one view to second view swift
Trying to pass array of dictionaries from view A to second view B in swift.
In view A, using a hidden navigation link in the view to push view B and send arrayMergeT100 to view B
@State var arrayMergeT100 = [[String:Any]]()

NavigationLink(destination:ShowBookChoices(bookOptions: self.$arrayMergeT100),
           isActive: self.$pushActive) {
             EmptyView()
        }.hidden()

View B, trying to access values for key "synopsis" and getting two errors on this line "if let index = bookOptions.index(forKey: "synopsis")  {".  Error 1- Incorrect argument label in call (have 'forKey:', expected 'where:') and Error 2-Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '([String : Any]) throws -> Bool'.   Changing forKey: to where: does not make Error2 go away
struct ShowBlindDateChoices: View {
    @Binding public var bookOptions: [[String:Any]]
    var body: some View {
                VStack{
                    if let index = bookOptions.index(forKey: "synopsis")  {
                        let _ = print(bookOptions[index].key, ":", bookOptions[index].value)
                    }


Why do you have a [[String:Any]] in the first place? What data are you storing in there? Can you show an example? You should consider writing a struct instead.

This is SwiftUI code. You should add that tag to your question.

Try this example code to access the keys and values of your construct:
if let index = bookOptions.firstIndex(where: { $0["synopsis"] != nil })  {
     print(bookOptions[index])
     print(bookOptions[index].keys)
     print(bookOptions[index].values)
 }

Or:
if let index = bookOptions.firstIndex(where: { $0["synopsis"] != nil }),
    let test = bookOptions[index].first {
    print(test)
    print(test.key)
    print(test.value)
}

